# Nginx over Apache with Laravel give rewrite_mod problems

Tags: apache2, nginx

Im running Nginx over Apache.

I Nginx listens to port `80` and proxy it to port `8080`, which Apache listens to.

So far it works for direct url to files, like `domain.com` and `domain.com/index.php`.

But if I go to `domain.com/test`, it says `404 Not Found nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)` even that I have set up a `route` for `/test`.

Here is my nginx config for the domain:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        access_log /var/www/site.com/logs/nginx.access.log;
        error_log /var/www/site.com/logs/nginx.error.log;
        root /var/www/site.com/public_html/public;
        index index.php index.html;
        server_name site.com;
        location \ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ index.php/$uri;
        }
        location ~* ^.*\.php$ {
                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                        return 404;
                }
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }
        location ~ /\.(ht|git) {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

And here is the Apache config for the domain:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerName site.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site.com/public_html/public/
        CustomLog /var/www/site.com/logs/apache.access.log common
        ErrorLog /var/www/site.com/logs/apache.error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Note: The nginx error log says: `2014/10/25 10:41:35 [error] 24014#0: *4 open() "/var/www/site.com/public_html/public/test" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.45.67.890, server: site.com, request: "GET /test HTTP/1.1", host: "site.com"`

Comment: The only issue I see that with that configuration you are serving statics file with both apache and Nginx which defeats the performance boost. I can across your post looking for an answer to the same issue. I have yet to find it, however I wanted to make anyone looking for this post was aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using nginx already, why not ditch Apache+mod_php for php-fpm? That avoids the need for a proxy.

After installing `php5-fpm`, add this vhost, and enable it with `sudo ln -s ../sites-available/example.com.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com.conf
server {
    listen 80;    
    server_name     example.com;
    root            /var/www/example.com/public_html/public;

    access_log      /var/www/example.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log       /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log;

    # Disallow access to hidden files (.htaccess, .git, etc.)
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }

    # Some locations will never contain PHP files, handle it in the server
    location ~ ^/(robots.txt|favicon.ico)(/|$) {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location = /index.php {
        # Disable direct access to the source code of index.php. If you have a
        # Laravel route for '/index.php', copy the @php_router block below.
        return 404;
    }

    location / {
        # Try to serve the static files, otherwise call into PHP
        try_files $uri @php_router;
    }

    location @php_router {
        include fastcgi_params;
        # If you move index.php outside public/, adjust it here.
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here is something that people trying to do the same should really know. So here is my shares.

I come to a solution with the following:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        access_log /var/www/site.com/logs/nginx.access.log;
        error_log /var/www/site.com/logs/nginx.error.log;
        root /var/www/site.com/public_html/public;
        index index.php index.html;
        server_name site.com;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }
        location ~* ^.*\.php$ {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }
        location ~ /\.(ht|git) {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

The first thing is, I added the proxy settings for `location / {`, as else it might not send you to Apache.

The next thing I did was removing `try_files` from all locations, as Apache uses `.htaccess` to configure this.

And that was my solution.